# Django ModelForms Radio Buttons with CSS

Tags: css, django-models, django-forms

So I am experimenting with Django Forms and I am now in the process of learning how to style Forms.

Here is my Code,

```
{% for field in form %}
<form class="form-contact" action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
                name="{{ field.name }}"
                id="id_{{ field.name }}"
                placeholder="{{field.label}}"
               </div>
        </fieldset>
       </form>
   {% endfor %}
```

Now I have 3 models in this Form, Two are text input and the 3rd is a list which uses radio buttons -

However the radio buttons do not show with my CSS - They do however show when there is no CSS styling - can anyone point me into a direction as too why?

FYI - very new to Django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your CSS with us?

Comment: Hi Sandy, The CSS is from (https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) this is a Material design template for Bootstrap - It works perfectly on all other aspects of the site but for some reason updating Forms seems to be an issue

Answer (score 0):

This form only contains one text input which is not closed (missing > after placeholder)

```
placeholder="{{field.label}}">
```

You need to provide more info.

**Update :**
the for tag is in the wrong place, check this code

```
<form class="form-contact" action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
            name="{{ form.field1.name }}"
            id="id_{{ form.field1.name }}"
            placeholder="{{form.field1.label}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
            name="{{ form.field2.name }}"
            id="id_{{ form.field2.name }}"
            placeholder="{{form.field2.label}}">
            <input type="radio" class="form-control"
            name="{{ form.field3.name }}"
            id="id_{{ form.field3.name }}"
            placeholder="{{form.field3.label}}">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Maybe you want django to generate the inputs for you and still have some control aver css style, use this :

```
<form class="form-contact" action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-control">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
        <div class="foo">
            <button class="bar" id="login-btn">Se Connecter</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and in **forms.py** add **widgets attrs** :

```
field1=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'some_class'}))
```

change field1, field2, field3 with your 3 field names.

Comment: I have updated the code to show my form loop(forgot to add 1st time round) This is looping over all models in forms as text, when I change <input = 'Text'> to < input = 'radio'> all inputs become radio buttons - I just don't know how to have both at the same time? Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi Khalil, many thanks for the help - I ended up using crispy forms in the end - for some reason the form still does not use the CSS I want and gives the generic bootstrap form, I think my templates are messed up a little - I'll run a few more test on this and see where I have went wrong. again thanks for the time, once I have a answer I'll be sure to post it here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my CSS files were indeed configured wrong, a simple replacement has resolved the issue.

Thanks to everyone who was kind enough to try and help with the answer.